# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIUserNotificationSettings' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift2

I had this code working with Swift 1.2 and then I upgrade and it breaks. In the screenshot below, I have both the Swift 1.2 and Swift 2 versions.

```
// Register the notification settings.
//swift1.2
//let newNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: categoriesForSettings as! Set<NSObject>)

//swift2
let newNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: categoriesForSettings as Set<NSObject>)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because initializer require `Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>`, not `Set<NSObject>`. Method declaration looks like this:

```
public convenience init(forTypes types: UIUserNotificationType, categories: Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>?)
```

So change your code to:

```
let notificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Sound ...
let categoriesForSettings: Set<UIUserNotificationType> = ...
let newNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: categoriesForSettings)
```